# TS2531: Object is possibly 'null'

Tags: angular, typescript

I have the following function:-

```
uploadPhoto() {
    var nativeElement: HTMLInputElement = this.fileInput.nativeElement;

    this.photoService.upload(this.vehicleId, nativeElement.files[0])
        .subscribe(x => console.log(x));
}
```

however on the nativeElement.files[0], I am getting a typescript error, "Object is possibly 'null'".  Anyone can help me solve this issue?

I tried to declare the nativeElement as a null value, however did not manage to succeed.

Thanks for your help and time.

Answer (score 91, accepted):

`files` is defined to be `FileList | null` so it can be `null`.

You should either check for `null` (using an `if`) or use a "Non-null assertion operator" (`!`) if you are sure it is not `null`:

```
if(nativeElement.files != null) {
    this.photoService.upload(this.vehicleId, nativeElement.files[0])
        .subscribe(x => console.log(x));
}

//OR
this.photoService.upload(this.vehicleId, nativeElement.files![0])
    .subscribe(x => console.log(x));
```

**Note:**

The "Non-null assertion operator" will not perform any runtime checks, it just tells the compiler you have special information and you know `nativeElement.files` will not be `null` at runtime.

If `nativeElement.files` is `null` at runtime, it will generate an error. This is not the safe navigation operator of other languages.

Comment: Yes it does, I prefer second one though, more concise

Comment: @Johann Yes, but be aware, if `nativeElement.files` is `null` at runtime, you will get an error. `!` does not perform runtime checks, it just tells the compiler you **know** `nativeElement.files` will never be `null` and to suppress the error.

Comment: Yes nativeElement.files should never be null according to my logic

Comment: @Johann Ok, it should be fine then for you. I added a note to the answer though to make sure this is clear to everyone what `!` does :)

Comment: Perfect!  Thanks Titian

Answer (score 37):

TypeScript 3.7 got released in 11/2019. Now "**[Optional Chaining](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html#optional-chaining)**" is supported, this is the easiest and most secure way of working with potentially null-able values:

You simply write:

```
nativeElement?.file?.name
```

**Note the Question-Mark**! They check for null/undefined and only return the value, if none of the properties (chained with dots) is null/undefined.

Instead of

```
if(nativeElement!=null && nativeElement.file != null) {
  ....
}
```

But imagine something more complex like this: `crm.contract?.person?.address?.city?.latlang` that would otherwise a lot more verbose to check.

Comment: Very interesting! What are the downsides? Seems like an improvement. There always are pros and cons of course.

Answer (score 18):

In addition to all the answers mentioned above, still if the user doesn't want the strict null checks in its application, we can just simply disable the `strictNullChecks` property in our `tsconfig.json` file.

```
{
 ...
 "angularCompilerOptions": {
 "strictNullChecks": false,
 ...
 }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

If you are sure that there is a file in all cases.
You need make compiler to be sure.

```
(nativeElement.files as FileList)[0]
```

Answer (score 2):

Using the answer from Markus which referenced optional chaining, I solved your problem by casting `nativeElement` to `HTMLInputElement` and then accessing the `0th` file by using `.item(0)` with the optional chaining operator `?.`

```
uploadPhoto() {
    var nativeElement = this.fileInput.nativeElement as HTMLInputElement

    this.photoService.upload(this.vehicleId, nativeElement?.files?.item(0))
        .subscribe(x => console.log(x));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you.
I had the same issue. In older version Ionic was all right. After update TS2531.
Now the function have two non-null assertion operator:

```
async saveToStorage(jsonMessage){
  await this.storage.set(jsonMessage["key"],jsonMessage["value"]);
  document.getElementsByTagName('iframe').item(0)!.contentWindow!.postMessage'{"type": "storage-save","result": "ok","key": "' + jsonMessage["key"] + '"}',"*");
}
```

Answer (score -2):

app.component.html

```
Enter your Name :<input [value]="data1" (input)='data1=$event.target.value'><br>
Enter name :{{data1}}
```

app.component.ts

```
data1:any = 'yash';
```

Comment: What does this have to do with the question?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).