# How to deal with 'Object is possibly undefined' error in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

I have a function where a param may be a string or undefined, but then a validation check that throws an error if it's undefined. Any further code is guaranteed that the param is defined, but I'm now fighting against the TypeScript casting of it potentially being undefined. What's the nice way in TypeScript to deal with this issue?

```js
import { validatePetFields } from "../models/pets";

interface controllerParams {
   req: {
      petName?: string;
   };
}

export default async ({ req }: controllerParams): Promise<any> => {

   validatePetFields(req, [
      "petName",
   ]); // this function intentionally throws a JS error if petName is undefined

   console.log(req.petName.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + req.petName.slice(1)); // throws TypeScript error: Object is possibly 'undefined'
};
```

Comment: As you now know the property is non-null, `req.petName!` can tell the compiler as much.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49431880/ts2531-object-is-possibly-null/49432007#49432007

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a type guard but you would have to wrap the validate call in an if statement. This basically tells the compiler that if that function returns true, inside the if block the type of req is now a derived type that has all those keys (passed as parameters) as required.

Something like:

```
type HasKeys<T, K extends keyof T> = T & { [Key in K]-?: T[Key] };

// function in a function to infer the key types 
// unfortunately it can't infer the type of the req 
// since it needs to be passed in the second function
// you could fix type inference for req by passing it as an argument to both functions
function validatePetFields<T>() {
    return function <K extends keyof T>(obj: T, ...keys: K[]): obj is HasKeys<T, K> {
        for (const key of keys) {
            if (obj[key] === void 0) {
                throw new Error('not valid');
            }
        }
        return true;
    };
}

interface Request {
    petName?: string;
}

export default async (req: Request): Promise<any> => {
    if (validatePetFields<Request>()(req, 'petName')) {
        // no more error since petName is not optional here :)
        console.log(req.petName.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + req.petName.slice(1));
    }
};
```