# React Hooks and TypeScript Fetching API: Object is possibly 'null'

Tags: reactjs, typescript, api, react-hooks

I'm doing a tutorial on React Hooks and fetching data. Here's my component to fetch customers and map them out in a list:

```ts
const useFetch = (url: string) => {
  const [customers, setCustomers] = useState<null | []>(null);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);

  // Similiar to componentDidMount() and componentDidUpdate()
  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      const result = await axios(url);
      setCustomers(result.data);
      setLoading(false);
    };
    fetchData();
  });

  return { customers, loading };
};

const url = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users';

export const LatestCustomers: React.FC<Props> = ({
  description
}: Props): JSX.Element => {
  const { customers, loading } = useFetch(url);

  return (
    <Container>
      {loading ? (
        <div>...Loading...</div>
      ) : (
        <tr>
          {customers.map(customer => (
            <div key="user.id">{customer.name}</div>
          ))}
        </tr>
      )}
    </Container>
  );
};
```

With that, I got the error:

```
Object is possibly 'null'.  TS2531

    108 |               ) : (
    109 |                 <tr>
  > 110 |                   {customers.map(customer => (
        |                    ^
    111 |                     <div key="user.id">{customer.name}</div>
    112 |                   ))}
    113 |                 </tr>
```

How do I solve this?

Comment: maybe `const { customers = [], loading } = useFetch(url);` will solve

Comment: There are several solutions to the problem, but basically either: 1. make sure it's never null; or 2. deal with the possibility that it might be null (`null.map` is a `TypeError`).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TS2531: Object is possibly 'null'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49431880/ts2531-object-is-possibly-null)

Answer (score 1):

Because the type supplied to `useState` is `null | []` then `customers` is given that type signature.

There are a couple of ways to deal with this. My suggestion would be to start with an empty array:

```
const [customers, setCustomers] = useState<[]>([]);
```

Alternatively if you wish to maintain the optional typing then you should check `customers` is not `null` first:

```
{customers && customers.map(customer => ( ...
```

Or if you're really sure it will always be defined you could use the [TypeScript non-null assertio](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#non-null-assertion-operator)n `!` operator:

```
{customers!.map(customer => (
```

Comment: I tried all of them, it gives `Property 'name' does not exist on type 'never'.`

Comment: So the problem in your question is solved but now TS is expecting customer to be typed. Do you have a type defined for your customer objects? If so, use it: `const [customers, setCustomers] = useState<Customer[]>([]);`

Answer (score 1):

A robust solution to handle nullable value could be to use an Option in fp-ts and `fromNullable`

https://github.com/gcanti/fp-ts/blob/master/src/Option.ts

Example:

`{fromNullable(customers).map(x=> {...})}`

Interesting article:
https://davetayls.me/blog/2018/05/20/fp-ts-01-working-with-nullable-values

Otherwise more straightforward approach:

`{customers && customers.map(x => ( ...`

Comment: But then it gives `Property 'name' does not exist on type 'never'.`

Comment: please post the code you are trying, I would be happy to help! thanks