# apply inline css to <html> tag in typescript on click

Tags: javascript, html, css, typescript

I am new to typescript and just got confused that how to apply inline CSS to  tag on click in typescript. I thought it was very simple but in typescript, things work differently as I tried with `document.querySelector("html").style.background = "blue"` but getting error like

```
 Object is possibly 'null'.  TS2531

       jumpToRelativePosition(anchors['chapter-main'], anchors['chapter-next']);
      document.querySelector("html").style.background = "blue

"
        ^
```

Please help me

Thanks in advance

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TS2531: Object is possibly 'null'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49431880/ts2531-object-is-possibly-null)

Answer (score 1):

when you need to have access to DOM Elements, you must always decalre them what element are they, `HTMlElement` is every type of element in HTML

```
const x = document.querySelector("html") as HTMLElement
```

if you will decalre with current element, for example you have input element mark as in ts `HTMLInputElement`

EDIT: **Do Not Forget to include "DOM" in you `lib` options in your tsconfig.json**

Comment: Did it help you?