# Object is possibly 'null'.ts(2531) in angular

Tags: angularjs, typescript

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eLzKD.png)

while using querySelector and addEventListener in angular it shows and error that Object is possibly 'null'.ts(2531).

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/49432007/2358409

Answer (score 0):

Because `document.querySelector` can either return an element or null. It returns null when it cannot find that element.
So, you would need to check if it's not a null.

```js
if (dragArea) {
// your event listener
}
```

Comment: i tried that but that is not working

Comment: can we connect, i really need help.

Comment: Did you put your event listener in that if statement?

Comment: yes i put but still its not showing. I really need help can you please connect on this lin https://meet.google.com/bgi-mqmx-bxy

Comment: i will be very thankful to you please help

Comment: How does your code look after you added the if statement?

Comment: i added that if condition the error goes but it is not working

Comment: man can you connect for a minute with me. i will show you my problem